# Enum trick in C++/CLI

Tags: arrays, enums, c++-cli

In native C++ we could use enum trick in class definition:

```
namespace EFoo
{
  enum { a = 10; };
}

class Foo
{
   // Declare an array of 10 integers.
   int m_Arr[EFoo::a];  
};
```

However, with managed enum in C++/CLI,

```
public enum class EFoo
{
  a = 10,
};
```

EFoo::a couldn't be converted implicitly to int,
so the enum trick wouldn't be allowed.

Is there any workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
arr[(int)EFoo.a];
```

Comment: Never thought that the compiler accepts casting in class definition.

Comment: Well, you're not casting the class or class definition. You are just casting the enum value.

Answer (score 4):

If you are just trying to achieve the '`enum` hack', you should not have to do that in any recent compiler, as they will support `static const` member declarations.

```
class Foo
{
private:
    static const int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
    int m_arr[ARRAY_SIZE];
};
```

Otherwise, doing an `int` cast like Jonathan Wood answered would work to change from a managed `enum` to an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont need the enacpsulation, why not declare it as an "enum" instead of the "enum class"? You can then use it without the cast, and also, without the classname .